# CodeIgniter passing variables to the views

Tags: codeigniter

In my CodeIgniter controller, I call a template view:

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $data['content'] = 'form';
            $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
        }
```

template.php view contains more view files, For example:

template.php:

```
<?php $this->load->view('includes/header'); ?>
<?php $this->load->view($content); ?>
<?php $this->load->view('includes/sidebar1'); ?>
<?php $this->load->view('includes/sidebar2'); ?>
<?php $this->load->view('includes/footer'); ?>
```

As I passed the content variable to the template view, which loads the form view.
Now the problem is that `sidebar1`, and `sidebar2` contains dynamic data from database. For example, sidebar1 contains some text which is fetched from database etc. So, How can i pass the dynamic data to the sidebar1, and sidebar2 views when calling mypage view.

Does it look messy or it is usual way to create layout in CodeIgniter. Are more efficient and easy approaches?
Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data passed into 'includes/template' from the $data array should also be passed into the views loaded inside this view by CodeIgniter, automatically. It can then be used in 'includes/sidebar1' in the same way as it is used in 'includes/template'.